# TornadoFX TableView. Scrolling the large amount of rows leads to UI freezing

Tags: kotlin, javafx, scroll, tableview, tornadofx

I have a windows desktop application on Kotlin and I'm using JDK Zulu11 with JavaFX and TornadoFX 2.0.0.
I faced the problem with scrolling of large amount of rows (~4mln) in the TableView.
I have something like a player and when it starts I just need to do autoscroll to the row corresponding to the player current position. So to make playing smooth I do it by calling scrollTo method every 50 milliseconds, 20 times per second.
I observed that approximately at 300000 UI starts freezing and at 500000 it is almost dead.
When I increase the delay from 50ms to 200ms or 500ms the situation is the same, UI gets freeze.
When I used JDK Zulu1.8 with JavaFX and TornadoFX 1.7.2 just for check all was perfect, all is playing very smooth and fast enough. With Oracle JDK 1.8 all is ok also.
But I need to migrate to JDK 11 because I have some important dependencies.

So the question is what is wrong with JDK 11(JavaFX) and TornadoFX 2.0.0 and how it can be fixed?

Thanks a lot for any help.

PS: Here is the minimal reproducible example, I just found some TableView example on javacodegeeks and modified it, so please chek with JDK1.8 and with OpenJDK11, I used Azul Zulu 11.
Also [here is the video](https://youtu.be/NiINdStOOfE) with demonstration.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;

public class FxTableViewExample1 extends Application {

    public static class Book {
        private SimpleIntegerProperty index;
        private SimpleStringProperty title;
        private SimpleStringProperty author;

        public Book () {
        }

        public Book (Integer i, String s1, String s2) {
            index = new SimpleIntegerProperty(i);
            title = new SimpleStringProperty(s1);
            author = new SimpleStringProperty(s2);
        }

        public int getIndex() {
            return index.get();
        }

        public void setIndex(int index) {
            this.index.set(index);
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title.get();
        }
        public void setTitle(String s) {
            title.set(s);
        }

        public String getAuthor() {
            return author.get();
        }
        public void setAuthor(String s) {
            author.set(s);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return (index.get() + ": " + title.get() + ", by " + author.get());
        }
    }


    private static final Integer COUNT = 10000000;
    private static final Integer DELTA = 5000;
    private static final Integer PERIOD = 50;

    public static final EventType<Event> ScrollEventType = new EventType<>("ScrollEvent");
    public static final EventType<Event> StopEventType = new EventType<>("StopEvent");

    public static class ScrollEvent extends Event {
        public Integer position = 0;
        public ScrollEvent(Integer position) {
            super(ScrollEventType);
            this.position = position;
        }
    }

    public static class StopEvent extends Event {
        public StopEvent() {
            super(StopEventType);
        }
    }

    private TableView<Book> table;
    private ObservableList<Book> data;
    private Text actionStatus;
    private Button startButton;
    private Button stopButton;
    private Integer count = 0;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty currentPositionProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    private Timer timer = null;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Table View Example 1");

        // Books label
        Label label = new Label("Books");
        label.setTextFill(Color.DARKBLUE);
        label.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.BOLD, 36));
        HBox labelHb = new HBox();
        labelHb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        labelHb.getChildren().add(label);

        // Table view, data, columns and properties

        table = new TableView<>();
        data = getInitialTableData();
        table.setItems(data);

        TableColumn<Book, Integer> indexCol = new TableColumn<>("Index");
        indexCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book, Integer>("index"));
        TableColumn<Book, String> titleCol = new TableColumn<Book, String>("Title");
        titleCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book, String>("title"));
        TableColumn<Book, String> authorCol = new TableColumn<Book, String>("Author");
        authorCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book, String>("author"));

        table.getColumns().setAll(indexCol, titleCol, authorCol);
        table.setPrefWidth(450);
        table.setPrefHeight(300);
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

        table.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(
                new RowSelectChangeListener());

        // Status message text
        actionStatus = new Text();
        actionStatus.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);

        startButton = new Button("Play");
        stopButton = new Button("Stop");
        stopButton.setDisable(true);

        currentPositionProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        table.scrollTo(newValue.intValue());
                        table.getSelectionModel().select(newValue.intValue());
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        primaryStage.addEventHandler(ScrollEventType, new EventHandler<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                if (event.getEventType() == ScrollEventType) {
                    currentPositionProperty.set(((ScrollEvent)event).position);
                }
            }
        });
        primaryStage.addEventHandler(StopEventType, new EventHandler<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                if (timer != null) {
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer = null;
                }
            }
        });

        startButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                count = 0;
                startButton.setDisable(true);
                stopButton.setDisable(false);

                if (timer == null) {
                    timer = new Timer(true);
                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            count++;
                            int position = count * DELTA;
                            if (position >= COUNT) {
                                Event.fireEvent(primaryStage, new ScrollEvent(COUNT));
                                Event.fireEvent(primaryStage, new StopEvent());
                            } else {
                                Event.fireEvent(primaryStage, new ScrollEvent(position));
                            }
                        }
                    }, 0, PERIOD);
                }
            }
        });
        stopButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                startButton.setDisable(false);
                stopButton.setDisable(true);
                if (timer != null) {
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer = null;
                }
            }
        });

        HBox hbox = new HBox(20);
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(startButton, stopButton);

        // Vbox
        VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(labelHb, table, actionStatus, hbox);

        // Scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 500, 475); // w x h
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // Select the first row
        table.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        Book book = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        actionStatus.setText(book.toString());
        
    } // start()

    private class RowSelectChangeListener implements ChangeListener<Number> {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, 
                Number oldVal, Number newVal) {
            int ix = newVal.intValue();
            if ((ix < 0) || (ix >= data.size())) {
                    return; // invalid data
            }
            Book book = data.get(ix);
            actionStatus.setText(book.toString());  
        }
    }
    
    private ObservableList<Book> getInitialTableData() {
        List<Book> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < COUNT) {
            list.add(new Book(i++, "The Thief", "Fuminori Nakamura"));
            list.add(new Book(i++, "Of Human Bondage", "Somerset Maugham"));
            list.add(new Book(i++, "The Bluest Eye", "Toni Morrison"));
            list.add(new Book(i++, "I Am Ok You Are Ok", "Thomas Harris"));
            list.add(new Book(i++, "Magnificent Obsession", "Lloyd C Douglas"));
            list.add(new Book(i++, "100 Years of Solitude", "Gabriel Garcia Marquez"));
            list.add(new Book(i++, "What the Dog Saw", "Malcolm Gladwell"));
            list.add(new Book(i++, "The Fakir", "Ruzbeh Bharucha"));
            list.add(new Book(i++, "The Hobbit", "J.R.R. Tolkien"));
            list.add(new Book(i++, "Strange Life of Ivan Osokin", "P.D. Ouspensky"));
            list.add(new Book(i++, "The Hunt for Red October", "Tom Clancy"));
            list.add(new Book(i++, "Coma", "Robin Cook"));
        }
        return FXCollections.observableList(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create and post a [mre] demonstrating the issue. (Note you're probably more likely to get help if you do this in Java, rather than Kotlin, because there's a larger user base.)

Comment: Also: *"I do it by calling scrollTo method every 50 milliseconds, 20 times per second. I observed that approximately at 300000"*. 300,000/20=15,000. So this would take 15,000 seconds, which is over four hours. What am I missing?

Comment: James_D, 300000 and 500000 means rows not a time.

Comment: Yes, I know. If you are scrolling 300000 rows and you scroll 20 rows per second, it would take four hours. Please also read my first comment.

Comment: James_D, Actually the player can process more than 20 rows per second, it can be 100 or 1000, so every 50ms I call scrollTo() not to the next row but to the next row which is corresponding to player position, it can be +1000 rows, this value depends on internal logic of rows data processing. For example I have 1000000 packets of data and every packet has timestamp, and the first packet has timestamp 01.01.1970-00:00:00 and the last packet has timestamp 01.01.1970-00:00:10, so I have 1mln data packets whithin10 seconds time interval, they will not played 50000 seconds but only 10.

Comment: So where is the [mre]?

Comment: James_D, Just added, please check it. Thanks.

Comment: worksforme (fx17): smooth scrolling by keyboard - but the example is missing some code to scroll chunks repeatedly as you describe

Comment: kleopatra, Yes I skipped the code to scroll chunks repeatedly, but if it is freezing while dragging the scrolling thumb by mouse just imagine how it will work when scrolling events come every 50ms, 20 times per second.
I cannot use fx17, TornadoFX doesn't support it yet.

Comment: There is the same picture with JDK17.

Comment: for me it doesn't freeze when dragging the scrollbar thumb .. fx17 is simply the version I have here on my dev machine, don't expect much change in comparison to fx11 (don't remember much change that might be related to performance)

Comment: in other words: the code doesn't seem to be an example of the problem you describe - at least not in my context ;)

Comment: same for fx11 .. looks/feels fine so far

Comment: kleopatra, Thank you for your help, I've updated the example please check it. Thanks.

Comment: don't see any freezing running the most recent example: after pressing start, the table scrolls smoothly (both fx11, fx17). BTW: firing events off the FX-application thread is wrong (well, doesn't make a difference here and I didn't find anything concrete, but dispatching events might have internal state changes which might have unpredictable side-effects) - better use fx concurrency support.

Comment: kleopatra, Did you use JDK Zulu 11/17 with integrated JFX?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by using OpenJDK11 and separate OpenJFX15 instead of Zulu JDK11+JFX.

Comment: Why 15? That's outdated? Why can't you use the current 19 right away?

Comment: mipa, TornadoFX suppors only JDK11 and JFX15

Comment: I doubt that it would make any difference. 15 was probably just the current version when TornadoFX was last updated. But who knows ...

Comment: mipa, Zulu JDK11 contains JFX19, I guess the problem was in JFX19.